# Hide element based on attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a button I'm using to toggle between displaying yes/no 'in-policy' divs

```
<form>
<input type="radio" id="Policy0" name="Policy" value="0" onclick="filterHotel();"><label for="Policy0">All</label>
</form>
<script type="application/javascript">
var Policy = $('input:radio[name=Policy]:checked').val()
if (Policy == 0) {  
 $('form [data-policy="0"]').toggle();              
}
</script>

<div id="24448" data-policy="0">Data here</div>
<div id="24448" data-policy="1">Data here</div>
```

With the code above I can successfully show/hide the correct div, but my issue is I don't want to wrap my input in a form element. Is there a way to reference based on a value in an attribute?

I've tried `$('input[attr=data-policy][value="0"]').toggle();` but that doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: `$('input[data-policy="0"]').toggle();` does not work, i don't get an error, but it doesn't hide a div with an attribute of `data=policy="0"` I also tried `data-policy=0` with no luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
$('[data-policy="0"]').toggle();
```

For further info, you can take a look at [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) documentation

Comment: I tried this before, but this also does not work. I'm using jQuery 1.8.1, but changing my version to 1.8.2 didn't affect anything. I'm not sure where else to look for an error.

Comment: I reviewed your question. It was not working because the tag was not `input`, it was `div`. The updated answer will toggle any tag that has data-policy=0

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

In essence, you want to use the attribute name like so:

```
$('input[data-policy="0"]').toggle();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The correct CSS (and thus, jQuery) selector for that is `[attribute=value]`, so, to select items with `data-policy="0"` you should use `[data-policy=0]`.

Other available selectors are "has attribute": `[attribute]`, "contains": `[attribute*=value]`, "starts with": `[attribute^=value]` and "ends with": `[attribute$=value]`.

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique, so why not use the ID ?

```
var Policy = $('#Policy0:checked').val();
$('#Policy0').toggle(Policy===0);
```

Comment: I will have multiple filters that need to be applied and I thought this way would be easier given all the separate filters. (that I didnt list in my question for simplicity)